# Property 'passwordConfirm' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I already have my password confirm on my component but I am receiving the error mentioned above , what seem to cause this error why cant it see the passwordConfirm ?

#ts

```
this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      password: [
        '',
        [
          this.validatePasswordRequired,
          this.validateMinimumPassword,
          this.validatePasswordUpperCase,
          this.validatePasswordLowerCase,
          this.validatePasswordSpecialCharacter,
          this.validateOneNumber
        ]
      ],
      passwordConfirm:[ '',
      [Validators.required, this.equalWithPasswordValidator],]
    });
```

#html

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>New password</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="password" type="{{(showPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}">
            <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword()">
              {{!showPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Confirm new password</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="passwordConfirm" type="{{(showPassword === false)?'passwordConfirm':'text'}}">
            <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword()">
              {{!showPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="passwordConfirm.hasError('required')">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.get('passwordConfirm').hasError('notEqual')">>
              Password does not match
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a getter titled passwordConfirm, this following line doesn't know what passwordConfirm is and is trying to find that related value in your .TS file.

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="passwordConfirm.hasError('required')">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
```

Update to this

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.get('passwordConfirm').errors?.required">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
```

Same goes for other controls.